# Semidirect product of Lie superalgebras

Tags: lie-algebras, lie-superalgebras

I am studying Lie superalgebrs and need the concept of semidirect product for the case of Lie superalgebras. May you please give me some information on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See for example the article [Non-abelian tensor product and homology of Lie superalgebras](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.1750.pdf) by Garcia-Martinez et al, Definition 2.2. It is quite similar to the case of Lie algebras. The article [A Sketch of L ie Superalgebra Theory](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1103900590) of V. Kac describes the semidirect product as follows (page 33):"Direct and semidirect sum of superalgebras is defined as usual."